# Why is the URL for a jQuery GET request calculated inconsistently?

Tags: jquery

My page is "https://localhost:44354/PageNameSpace", and I have a jQuery .get call to a specific method of a specific controller.

```
$.get("Controller/ControllerMethod", { params }, function (result) {
```

Normally, this works properly, the call is executed to the expected URL.

```
https://localhost:44354/Controller/ControllerMethod
```

My problem is: Sometimes this page can be opened from an URL that contains parameters (not sure if this is important).
When this happens, for some reason, the exact same get call is exectued to this URL:

```
https://localhost:44354/PageNameSpace/Controller/ControllerMethod
```

Obviously this returns 404 and I get an error.
An easy solution is to pass `window.location.origin + "/Controller/ControllerMethod"` as the URL, but that doesn't explain why this happens. jQuery documentation doesn't seem to mention anything about how the URL is handled internally and I couldn't seem to find anything online.

Thanks in advance.

Edit. Passing "/Controller/ControllerMethod" instead of "Controller/ControllerMethod" seems to work, so now my question is, what is the right way to pass the URL? Is it specified somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: As I know jQuery ```get()``` method is for **loading data from the server using a HTTP GET request**. If you have some codes that may change the url **after** that request, you should put them and explain your exact problem clearly.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. 
My URL does not change after the request.
My URL is always the same. The only variable scenario is that it may contain parameters, but if it does, the page has loaded with them, and the URL won't change as long as you don't navigate to another page. 
The problem I'm facing is that the URL that when I pass the final part of the URL to jQuery, the origin part is calculated including the NameSpace, even thought I wouldn't expect it.

Comment: I would think you should use "/Controller/ControllerMethod" regardless, since that will allow it to work even if the page URL is completely different. In other words, if you specify the relative URL of the controller as always starting from the root folder, you can call it from anywhere. As for why you had problems when there were parameters, you didn't provide an example so I can only guess that the server interpreted `PageNameSpace` as a folder and tried to access `Controller/ControllerMethod` below that folder.

Comment: A url starting without a `/` is a relative URL - *relative to the current page's URL*.  If the url is always the same, then start it with a `/`.  How the browser determines the current page's URL depends on the URL.  If your page is "..PageNameSpace/?id=1" then it will add PageNameSpace - essentially, up to the last `/`.

Comment: The *correct* way to pass the URL is the one that works.   There may be a server-side solution, eg in Asp.Net-MVC, you would use `$.get("@Url.Action("ControllerMethod", "Controller")` and it will always resolve the correct url.  This is needed if you re-base your entire applications (ie if *all* paths have an extra component) and any *hardcoded* paths would stop working.